# Is Glassfish/JBoss/Geronimo a virtual machine?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have some problems understanding what the different Java platforms are, like what they give you, what they do and so on.

When you download a Java EE SDK you get Glassfish, which is the reference implementation of the Java EE API. But Glassfish is not a JVM right? It is just a set of API's/libraries that implement the Java EE 6 specification? The same applies to JBoss, it is just a set of API's/libraries written by another company?

So what you get when you download the Java EE SDK from oracle.com is the Glassfish implementation right?

In order to get the compiler, debugger, JVM and "core" API you need the Java SE SDK too? But is the API, compiler, debugger and JVM just a reference implementation too from oracle? Is it possible to download alternatives (not going to, but just trying to understand the concept).

Finally, when you compile and run a Java EE application....you are using a JVM (not Glassfish) to execute this, but you have access to the EE libraries as well.

I would appriciate if somebody could help me understand the concepts of this correctly and straigth things up of I have written anything wrong above.

Answer (score 4):

To answer your title: no, all of them are application servers and not a virtual machine.

> But GlassFish is not a JVM right?

Correct, [GlassFish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GlassFish) is a fully Java EE implemented application server. Which means that you can write Java EE applications and run it on GlassFish.

> So what you get when you download the Java EE SDK from oracle.com is
>   the Glassfish implementation right?

If you downloaded Java EE SDK from Oracle, it's **bundled** with GlassFish.

> In order to get the compiler, debugger, JVM and "core" API you need
>   the Java SE SDK too? But is the API, compiler, debugger and JVM just a
>   reference implementation too from oracle? Is it possible to download
>   alternatives (not going to, but just trying to understand the
>   concept).

You need a JVM to run anything Java based. Glassfish runs on the JVM. Your Java EE application runs in GlassFish. GlassFish is your server and not a JVM.

You need a JDK if you want to write Java application, since the JDK (Java Development Kit) contains `javac` (Java Compiler).

> Finally, when you compile and run a Java EE application....you are
>   using a JVM (not Glassfish) to execute this, but you have access to
>   the EE libraries as well.

You are running your Java EE application in GlassFish. GlassFish will look at your application configuration and knows how to execute your Java EE implemented application. GlassFish is run by the JVM (since it's written in Java).

Hope this helps.

Wikipedia on [Glassfish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GlassFish).

Comment: So, Glassfish is a server written in Java and provides all the things specified in the Java EE specification the the applications that it contains? When you say bundled with Glassfish...what else is it?

Comment: For the first question, correct. For the second question, It's the Java EE SDK packaged with Glassfish. Nothing more.

Comment: I see, helped a lot. So the JVM contains all the Java classes such as String, Exceptions etc? These classes are not compiled and bundled with my own classes when I make a JAR for example?

Answer (score 1):

You're confused between Java SE (for which a JVM can be an implementation, like OpenJDK's HotSpot) and Java EE which has GlassFish as the reference implementation (hence its presence in the SDK) and JBoss, Geronimo, etc... as other implementations of JavaEE.

[Java EE](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/) requires Java SE, so a JVM is indeed required by any application server, GlassFish included. Some Java EE SDK bundles come with a JVM in case you don't already have one. And yes, the Java SE SDK comes with all the tools you expect (compiler, interpreter, etc...).

One can use Java SE (which defines a [large set of API's](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/)) without Java EE if you don't need a "container" to abstract away the integration to databases for instance or provide services such as resource injection or more generally scalability across multiple users.

hope this helps...